# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 null

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am calling a service from one module to another module. but it throws an exception:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 null
>
> POST request for "http://localhost:80../.../...Report" resulted in 401
>   (null); invoking error handler.

I can able to hit this service from post man directly.
But when its called from spring boot module it throws error.

```
BaseResponseDTO baseResponseDTO = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:80../.../...Report", requestDTO, BaseResponseDTO.class);
```

error throws in this line

Comment: Is that the real url or did you sanitize it? Note that 401 is an Unauthorized error, do you have a (special) cookie maybe in Postman which makes the request succeed there?

Comment: I am not giving the whole url in this question. In post man i am passing authorization token in header. while calling the url from the module token also sending along with that. I am using same kind of code for other modules also. but i don't know why it is not working. and also i am not getting 401 Unauthorized. i am getting 401 null.

Comment: can you please paste the code you are using to send authorization token in the code? Also, enable debug mode for org.springframework.web.client package, that should help

Comment: authorization token is passing internally for the first module because of that i am getting access. From this module its not moving to the next module, here i don't need to set the token again. because i am already authorized. I am using the same way to connect with other modules also. only i am facing error in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I added authorization headers in MultiValueMap and i added object request in HttpEntity. here i added code.

MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
headers.add("Authorization", "bearer "+<TOKEN>);
HttpEntity<MyObject> httpEntityRequest = new HttpEntity<>(myObjectReference, headers);

BaseResponseDTO baseResponseDTO = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:80../.../...Report", httpEntityRequest , BaseResponseDTO.class);
```

Comment: I was having the same error. The issue was with the Auth Header Only, however i used restTemplate.exchange instead of postForObject